# Sysprep failed because of Miracastview

Tags: powershell, command-line, windows-10, sysprep

When I run sysprep on Windows 10, I am getting below error in the log file:

Package Windows.MiracastView_6.3.0.0_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy was installed for a user, but not provisioned for all users. This package will not function properly in the sysprep image.

I tried to remove MiracastView from powershell but no luck.

Please help to resolve this issue